# What is the tense of the archaic phrase "our ship was come"? Is it the same as "Spring is come"?

Tags: grammar

When authors have written, "Spring is come!," it means "Spring has come."

However in stories or plays by people from days long sped, I often come across this sort of sentence, for which unfortunately I cannot find a source offhand since this has been a lingering question in my mind to which I have paid scanty attention:

> When our ship **was** come to the shore, I said to my first-mate thus..."

Is this "was" the same as "had come"?

Comment: Aren't these just cases of "come" used adjectivally?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in the past, some verbs simply used *be* as an auxiliary verb, that nowadays take *have*.

The usage of the tense has not changed in your examples.

> Spring **is** come -> Spring **has** come. (present perfect, both times) 
>  
>   I **was** come -> I **had** come. (past perfect, both times)

Comment: I came accross the same thing in "the hobbit". It is written " the spring was come."
Thanks for the explanation but my mind is wondering if this is something from the romance languages. I know also Italian and a bit french. In these languages we use two auxilary verbs (to be and have) to make the past form. And mostly "to be" verb for verbs that show changing of a state or a kind of movement. (ie: sono andato a casa. = I went home or I was gone home) so can we assume the reason is this?!